# where is the best place to save game progress?

Tags: android, save, progress

I'm developing a quiz game and I want to save the progress... Actually I use sharedsettings, is easy and fast, but the user can delete program files and lose the progress. Same happens with a database. I should use a file? I'm only interesting to save a boolean for each question: "correct answered or not?"

Thank you!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SharedSettings. And you're already using it. It's very difficult to save a user from his/herself. If it's on the device then it can be destroyed either stupidly or maliciously. And don't forget that everything is a file and there's nothing you can put on the device that will be hack/idiot proof.

The only way to get around this would be to store user settings off the device via something like a web service (and backing database.) But I would say that if you're using SharedSettings...  you're OK. Leave it at that. I would only consider using an app-specific db if you expect the number of question you track to grow to a very large size and want more control over the data.

Comment: Thank you. I will continue using sharedSettings. If the data exceeds to much, I pose the possibility of use a database.

Answer (score 1):

Where in code logic?

In general, it's best to save any UI preferences at onPause. Android design wants you to never have a "save" button, rather save constantly.

As far as at each question, i guess you would save after answering each question?

Comment: If you reread the question you'll see that the OP is concerned not with `when` but with `where`. The `where` consideration is one of `safer` persistence.

Comment: As Paul said, the question it's where, not when. But you give me a interesting answer, I did not realize the onResume's potential